# Possible to manage Sub Accounts with Terraform? Multi Account Best Practices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

i'm setting up a multi account for aws and created a organization.
from here i want to setup all sub accounts manually.

first question comes to my mind if i have to go to all sub accounts now first manually to create access keys for that or if i could use terraform for that already?

second question is what are best practices to setup multiple accounts via terraform. lets say we always have a dev, test, prod environment where i want to add changes like polices to all sub accounts.

i was first thinking limit stuff with the organization policies and give developers even a root account for the sub accounts backed up by the deny policies from the organization. can i from the organization manage this accounts or should i create a terraform iam user in each account.

just a info how to do it in a clean nice way would help me a lot.
i went through the book terraform up and running the last days but could not find any answers for this question ...

thanks anyway for answers and infos!

cheers bin2hex

Comment: Here is an [open PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/14147) for an `aws_organization_account` resource. This is the original [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12337). Further, a [blog post](https://medium.com/@PatrikKarisch/part-2-automated-aws-multi-account-setup-with-terraform-and-onelogin-sso-44baaf563877) with some ideas on that topic.